# Is there a way to set a .style automatically before onClick js function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a responsive nav for a website I am building. I am using a transform:translateX css property to align the sidebar, where I use two js functions (show/hideMenu) to change the variable in the css property. The issue I am finding is that when reloading the mobile dimensions in the live server, the sidebar is either visible automatically or shows for a few seconds, which I assume is due to the transition time I have set in css.

A solution I feel may work would be have a value set before the initial showMenu button click upon loading into the page, however I am still in the beginning stages of learning js so I cant think of the syntax to do this correctly. Ive looked at multiple source codes for websites, as well as responsive navbar tutorials on youtube and have yet to find anything that helps. Setting the initial transform:translateX value in css doesnt work. Here is the code:

```js
var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");

function showMenu() {
  navLinks.style.transform = "translateX(0%)";
}

function hideMenu() {
  navLinks.style.transform = "translateX(100%)";
}
```

```css
.navlinks {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 0 0 50%;
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 80%);
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: left;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="brand-title">
    <h4>Bottoms Up Tiki Tours</h4>
  </div>

  <div id=navLinks class="navlinks">
    <div class="x" onClick="hideMenu()">
      <i class="bi bi-x"></i>
    </div>

    <ul class="navlist">
      <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li class=><a href="#prices">Prices</a></li>
      <li class=><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li class=><a href="#booking">Booking</a></li>
      <li class=><a href="https://www.facebook.com/bottomsuptikitours"><svg 
                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="13" height="13" 
                 fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-facebook" viewBox="0 0 16 
                 16"><path d="M16 8.049c0-4.446-3.582-8.05-8-8.05C3.58 0-.002 
                 3.603-.002 8.05c0 4.017 2.926 7.347 6.75 7.951v-5.625h- 
                 2.03V8.05H6.75V6.275c0-2.017 1.195-3.131 3.022-3.131.876 0 
                 1.791.157 1.791.157v1.98h-1.009c-.993 0-1.303.621-1.303 
                 1.258v1.51h2.218l-.354 2.326H9.25V16c3.824-.604 6.75-3.934 
                 6.75-7.951z"/></svg></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="burger" onClick="showMenu()">
    <i class="bi bi-list"></i>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up going way over my head and complicating it with JS but it helped with my understanding of JS. I used the aria-expanded states to set attributes upon click. This solved my issue. If anyone has any questions on how to do this feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Instead try using css like create button that when hovered on change the css property using transition from, to

Comment: Please try to provide reproducible code example for your answer. Other you could add your suggestions into the comment section under the original post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks! Ill definitely have to look into that to simplify it. I ended up going way over my head and complicating it with JS but it helped with my understanding of JS. I used the aria-expanded states to set attributes upon click.